# Minecraft - Command activating when enitiies = x-number using command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I am trying to figure out how to teleport someone within a radius, but only when there is one entity left within that radius. I was trying this:

```
/tp @p[c=1] x y z
```

But the `c` is only for how many people you wish to teleport. So my mind jumped to:

```
/tp @p[entity=1] x y z
```

But as far as I'm aware you, can't specify `entity` under @p. I am rather new to command blocks in general. Is it possible, and if yes, how? I would normally like to figure it out myself because I learn better that way, but this is too confusing for me. If it is possible I would rather just be told how to figure it out without giving me the complete answer, but at this point I'll be content with anything.

Comment: I have an idea to use one command block to active another if players within x radius=1. and the second command block just /tp @p x y z r=25 but again i'm new to command blocks and idk if this is doable or how to do it if it is.

Comment: I think you need to reform your question to be a little more clear. Are you trying to teleport a mob to a mob or a player to a mob or a mob to a player or a mob to coordinates or a player to coordinates? It's just slightly cunfusing.

Comment: I apologize, idk why i felt the need to keep it vague, i'm making a pvp arena, 4 teams of how many ever players each, 1 member from each team gets randomly selected and tp'ed to the center, when there is 1 player left in the arena alive, tp that player back to his or her starting location and then randomly select another 4 players to tp until there is 1 team left.

Comment: All right, thanks. Should be able to work on that.

Answer (score 0):

To do the radius:

```
/tp @p[c=1,r=3]
```

Where radius is 3.
You might want to look at this page:
[Command Selectors](http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Commands#Selectors)

If you could explain this comment I could help you with it.

> I have an idea to use one command block to active another if players within x radius=1. and the second command block just /tp @p x y z r=25 but again i'm new to command blocks and idk if this is doable or how to do it if it is.

Comment: My entire objective is to be able to:
 /tp <1 player> to  <x=a y=b z=c > when <1 entity> is left withing <x-radius>.
My idea was to use one command block to check for when one entity was left in the set radius and then to trigger a second command block to tp the last entity to the set location. I however did not know what commands to use nor if it was/is even possible.
i'm going to try Dova's method and see if i can get it to work, but if there is an alternate way to do this i would love to know it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a command block to repeatedly `/testfor @e[x=a,y=b,z=c,r=radius,c=1]` to send a redstone signal when the there is a player within `radius` distance from `a,b,c`. The `c`, as you showed, indicates the number of players, and `@e` makes it count entities rather than players. If you only want to count players, just return to `@a`. Then, connect this to a command block that has `/teleport @a[x=a,y=b,z=c,r=radius] <x> <y> <z>` with the same specifications as earlier, except `<x>,<y>,<z>` are where you want to teleport the target to.